# Submit form when :selected using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, search

I have a search form in my Rails 3 app. Most of the searches occur when checkboxes are checked/unchecked, however I have a search or two I'd like to perform with a select drop down. I'm using very basic jQuery to submit the form with checkboxes, and I've tried adapting it to the :selected selector as well. However it's not working. In troubleshooting the problem I'm wondering if my jQuery is the cause.

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(':selected').live('click',function() {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

I'm using [Ransack](http://rubygems.org/gems/ransack) for the search form. Here's the `<%= f.select %>` I'm using for the actual form:

```
<%= f.select :profile_subject, options_for_select([['Select', 0], ['Arts', 1], ['Biology', 2], ['Business', 3], ['Chemistry', 4], ['English', 5], ['Foreign Language', 6], ['Government', 7], ['Health', 8], ['History', 9], ['Math', 10], ['Physics', 11], ['Vocational', 12]]) %>
```

Comment: What is your intention here?  I think `:selected` is not really what you want, but I'm unsure what it is that you're trying to do.

Comment: Basically, when I select an option, I want that selection to submit the search form so the form renders the appropriate users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment.  I think you want to use `change` instead of `click`.  This way, the code will execute whenever the value is changed.

```
$(function(){
    $('select').live('change',function() {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using `:selected` is going to work. When the code runs, the user shouldn't have selected anything in your select element yet, so the event handler won't be attached.

Try using `$("select")` or the element's id or name to attach the event handler. Inside the event handler you can check to see if the element has been selected and then submit the form.